# Showing module can be decomposed

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an $R$-module and $\pi_1,\dots,\pi_k \in \operatorname{End}_R (M)$ such that the following conditions are satisfied:

1) $\pi_i ^2=\pi_i$;

2) $\sum_{i=1}^{k} \pi_i $ is the identity map;

3) $\pi_i \pi_j = 0$ for $i \neq j$.

 Set $M_i = \operatorname{Im}(\pi_i)$.

 I need to show that $M \cong M_1 \oplus \dots \oplus M_k$.

 I know there is a theorem saying that if $M$ is an $R$-module and $M_1,\dots,M_k$ are submodules of $M$, then $M \cong M_1 \oplus \dots \oplus M_k$ if and only if $M=M_1+\dots+M_k$ and $M_j  \cap \sum_{\substack{i=1, \\ i\neq j}}^{k} M_i = \{0_M\}$.

 How can show what I want to prove is equivalent to the conditions from the theorem?

Comment: First try the case for $k=2$ and see if that allows you a path forward. You should be able to use the theorem rather directly in this case. The $\pi_i$ that you have been given are what is called a set of orthogonal idempotents in the endomorphism ring of $M.$ These homomorphisms are important in decomposability, as your problem shows.

Comment: You can show it directly, no need for the theorem. What do you think is the isomorphism? You should think of the $\pi_i$ as orthogonal projections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Relation (2) says that for any $m\in M$, $m=\sum_{i=1}^k\pi_i(m)\in\sum_{i=1}^kM_i$.

There remains to show that $\;Mj\cap\sum\limits_{\smash[b]{\substack{i=1\\i\ne j}}^k}Mi=\{0\}$.
Suppose that
$$m_j=\sum\limits_{\substack{i=1\\i\ne j}}^k m_i,\qquad (m_j\in M_j, m_i\in M_i) $$
and apply $\pi_j$ to both sides.

Comment: When I was recalling how this proof went, it seemed that the condition that the maps be idempotent was not necessary. Am I missing something? I realize that projections are idempotent, but is this merely a bonus?

Comment: It is used in the second part, because $m_j\in\operatorname{Im}(\pi_j)$, so $\pi_j(m_j)=m_j$.

Comment: Right. Quite an oversight on my part. Thanks.